# How to consume multiple JSONs from a HTTPs keep-alive request?

Tags: node.js, json, http, stream, keep-alive

I have a node web server which listens on

```
this.app.use('/register-receiver', (req, res) => {
  const receiverId = req.query.id;
  res.status(200).set({
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });
  this.receivers[receiverId] = res;
});
```

It periodically sends a JSON payload to clients connected to `/register-receiver` with

```
this.receivers[receiverId].write(JSON.stringify({
  // some big json
}))
```

I have another node program which acts as a client that makes a connection to the server on startup.

```
const options = {
  agent: false,
  host: <my host>,
  defaultPort: <my port>
  path: `/register-receiver?id=${activeConfig.receiver.id}`
  headers: {
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
};

http.get(options, res => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', data => {
    try {
      const response = JSON.parse(data);
      // do stuff with response
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(`error ${e} with ${data}`);
    }
  });
  res.on('end', () => console.log(`connection finished`) )
})
```

The server needs to periodically send JSON payloads to the client. The client should receive these JSONs and do something with them. However, the problem is that large JSONs writes are chunked such that the client will receive the JSON in pieces. This breaks `JSON.parse(data)` and now the client doesn't know how to process the server payloads. I can't rely on `res.on('end')` to detect the the completion of a chunked write because this is a keep-alive request that should stay open forever.

I want to avoid designing my own protocol for combining JSON chunks because of it's complexity. It's not as simple as concatenating the strings since I could have interleaved JSON chunks if the server sends 2 large JSON payloads at the same time.

Is it possible to force the server to write the entire JSON as 1 chunk in the stream? How can I setup my client such that it establishes a "forever" connection with my server and listens for complete JSON payloads?

Comment: Welcome to TCP/IP.  You don't control what packets it arrives in.  You need either a length or a delineator to know how much to read before parsing or a stream parser.

Comment: FYI, you might want to consider webSocket or socket.io which will reassemble whole messages for you.

Comment: maybe check out json stream. but i think you better off using websocket and publisher / consumer model via a pubsub queue

Comment: I did consider websockets, but decided against it since I only need 1 way communication.

If I go with length, how would I specify the length of each JSON payload?

If I use a delineator, could I guarantee "chunk sizes" such that each chunk contains a predictable piece of the json?